# mySQL multiple data resolution query

Tags: mysql, union

I'm trying to select data at two different resolutions based on data points per unit of time.  Right now I'm just running two queries and joining them with a UNION.  To get the number resolutions I want I'm using this to achieve 1 data point per minute:

```
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime`) DIV 60
```

Just wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this?

```
SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime`)*1000) as `dt`, `value1`, `value2`
    FROM `table`
    WHERE `datetime` BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2018-01-01'
    GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime`) DIV 240
UNION
SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime`)*1000) as `dt`, `value1`, `value2`
    FROM `table`
    WHERE `datetime` BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2018-01-01'
    AND TIME(`datetime`) BETWEEN TIME('12:00:00') AND TIME('13:00:00')
    GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime`) DIV 60
ORDER BY `dt` ASC;
```

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  You have a `group by` key, but then have other unaggregated columns in the `select`s.  I would suggest that you delete this question and ask *another* question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: For the data I'm working with unaggregated columns are ok.  I just need a value from that time group, not a specific one.  The query does work, I'm just asking if there is a more efficient way to select two different time divisions of data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative I came across.  This one seems a little quicker and returns the actual values for the times selected instead of mySQL just picking one from each time group.

On this table `datetime` is an index.

```
SELECT a.`datetime`, a.`value1`, a.`value2`
    FROM `table` a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT `datetime`
        FROM `table`
        WHERE DATE(`datetime`) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2018-01-01'
        GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime`) DIV 240
    UNION
    SELECT `datetime`
        FROM `table`
        WHERE DATE(`datetime`) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2018-01-01'
        AND TIME(`datetime`) BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '13:00:00'
        GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime`) DIV 60
    ORDER BY `datetime`
) b on a.`datetime` = b.`datetime`;
```